# imagecache not displaying preset images

Tags: drupal

i tried to configure my imagecache..installed n enabled the module..now i created a cck for images..and set its test mode display as thumbnail preset linked to the node..

now when i am trying to add content to it, its not displaying the content on the node page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem,;) when I activated the "ImageAPI GD2" package under the ImageCache module activation form (admin site building).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can check:

- Go to /admin/content/node-type/YOURNODETYPE/display and make sure the image field is visible both in teaser and full view.
- Make sure proper permissions are set for the files/imagecache folder (the files folder is usually located in site_root/sites/default/)
- Check if the image shows up when you are on the node edit page

Answer (score 0):

To use image cache you need to check three things.

1. check right php extension(GD) is installed
2. check your folder permission(generally sites/all/files)
3. ckeck permission for the field is given for drupal